# Is a circular checkbox bad UI design?

Tags: checkboxes, radio-buttons

A radio button is normally presented as circular control but more recently checkboxes are also being presented with a rounded border making them look like radio buttons.

http://flatlogic.github.io/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/demo/

We have a UI design company working on a project at the moment and they have done the same thing.

So is a circular checkbox bad UI design?

Comment: In the github example linked above, the "Basic Checkbox" design is fine, the "Circled Checkbox" design looks wrong and should ideally be avoided (it's just a funky design element for the purpose of looking funky)

Comment: The short answer is yes absolutely it is bad - why you ask - well confusion kicks in.  Plain and simple.  Whenever there is any confusion present you've got something to worry about.

Comment: I find this amusing, because [mutually-exclusive radio buttons were square before the web](http://www.knowahead.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/car-radio-buttons.jpg)

Comment: The [help page](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) specifically tells you not to ask questions which already include the answer you want to hear.

Comment: I was asking whether this was a bad design or not, how else am I supposed to ask the question?

Comment: [Coming across this UI would feel kind of like finding a chocolate bar floating in the pool; it ***is*** a chocolate bar, right?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPxiXGr9nFM)

Comment: That link with round checkboxes and square radio buttons with checkmarks is just horrifying!

Comment: @Izkata : Except on computers, where the first radio buttons appeared on the Xerox Star 8010 (1981) and were round, and these round GUI elements were subsequently adopted by the Apple Lisa (1983), Visi-On (1983), Apple Macintosh (1984), Atari ST (1985), Commodore Amiga (1985), and Microsoft Windows (1985).  [This page](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/242-the-history-of-a-radio-button/) almost gets the order right.  Of course, [not all](http://www.radio-workshop.co.uk/feature-dac10.shtml) physical radio buttons were square.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots, so this question remains legible once the site you link to goes down?

Comment: I noticed in both google and apple photo apps, it is ok to use a circular check selection indicator. On a standard form, circle for radio and square for check, but why is it ok to use circular check selection in situations like photo galleries? [![example of circular check selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6jXp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6jXp.png)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/68850)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/68850)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## It Depends

We use circular "radio" buttons to indicate there's only one choice available in the group.

Square checkboxes are used to indicate that a more flexible entry is allowed (none, one, or several).  Individual choices are checked or unchecked.

If you're allowing none, one, or several options, use square checkboxes.
If you're only allowing one option, use a round option/radio button.

Allowing multiple choices for round checkboxes is just plain confusing.

Refer to the [Microsoft guidelines for Radio Buttons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742436(v=vs.85).aspx) for further reading.

> With a **radio button**, users make a choice among a set of mutually exclusive, related options. Users can choose one and only one option. Radio buttons are so called because they function like the channel presets on radios.
>
> With a **check box**, users make a decision between two clearly opposite choices. The check box label indicates the selected state, whereas the meaning of the cleared state must be the unambiguous opposite of the selected state. Consequently, check boxes should be used only to toggle an option on or off or to select or deselect an item.

In short, **radio buttons** offer a choice of a set of options (you have to listen to one radio station, you can't choose none or many).  **Checkboxes** allow you a yes/no to each of a set of options.

Comment: Absolutely agree

Comment: I agree with Pete too. It will be a tough sell to convince or educate your users to take rounded checkboxes, since every one is used to round radios and rectangular check boxes

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Microsoft Style Guide please?

Comment: @Bonner - Sorry, I can't.  Mine is in print format (I bought it many many years ago).  Online Microsoft documentation for radio buttons is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742436(v=vs.85).aspx)  I see that MS no longer use "option buttons" as a preferred term.  Navigating from that page will lead you to guidelines for other types of controls.

Comment: No problem, do you know the ISBN of the print format as I'd love to have a read of it at some point?

Comment: @Bonner - [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Manual_of_Style).  Although the documentation at the link in my answer above is probably more up to date.  The last edition of MSMOS was published back in 2012.

Comment: Why your answer begins with "it depends" when the rest of the answer boils down to "yes, round checkboxes are definitely bad design" ? I almost downvoted.

Comment: @Agent_L - Because the answer depends on how the radio buttons are used.  I answered the exact question in the comments above, my answer here differentiates between the use of radio buttons and checkboxes.  The OP should ideally follow the guidelines in my answer, not the github example that used round checkboxes.

Comment: From the phrasing of the question (and linked page) I understand that OP already knows the difference between radiobutton and a checkbox. The only way "depends" may be true is if one adds confusion by calling radiobutton a "single choice checkbox" - which you also clear up.

Answer (score 2):

Although Pete is right, to elaborate as to 'why' it is a bad design choice, is that it's simply a standard we're all accustomed to. Everyone will regocnize a set of square boxes instantly as more choices possible/checkboxes, and round ones as radio buttons/one choice.

Swapping these shapes will be confusing, and even if people find out the boxes don't work as normal, they'll still be unsure of whether the site/app is working like it's supposed to.

Comment: If they can't get such a simple thing correct, why trust them with your information, time, money, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the platform. I (and my colleagues) had the same question, especially after we found out our MAUI app used square checkboxes on Android and round ones on iOS. [This](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/maui/controls/checkbox/overview) is not the default MAUI control but it sheds some light on round checkboxes:

> The CheckBox follows the rendering guidelines of the operating system. As a result, on iOS it is visualized as a circle while Android and WinUI display it as a square.

When you open the default Mail app on iOS, and tap the 'Edit' button on the top right, you'll see [round checkboxes](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2023/01/25/how-to-organize-mailboxes-iphone/).